# Why is "_" undefined while "x" is a reference error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I enter `_` into a nodejs terminal, I get "undefined", but when I type in `x`, I get a reference error.  I thought underscores were just another character, why am I getting different results?

```
$ nodejs
> _
undefined
> x
ReferenceError: x is not defined
>
```

I thought both would give me a reference error.

Comment: It *is* just another identifier, so it must exist in scope: question is then only why, and what purpose.

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónRapela that doesn't seem applicable to this question

Comment: Not a duplicate of the “other” linked above. Op is questioning why one (arbitrary) identifier is not defined, while _ another (seemingly arbitrary) identifier is.

Comment: The posted one involving arbitrary code that happens to contain “x”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In node.js, `_` would return last expression's result.

If you try to using `_` as first command, it will return undefined.